# How to solve "expected a ; " error when sorting a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, comparator, function-definition

I am trying to sort vector using sort method.

here is my code

```
bool compare(const student * a, const student* b) 
{
    return *a.mark < *b.mark || (a.mark == b.mark && a.name < b.name);
}
sort(total_student.begin(), total_student.end(), compare);
```

I get error before `return`, which read `expected a ';'`, any idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Are you attempting to define a function within another function? This snippet is too small to figure out the problem otherwise, please provide a [mre]

Comment: You have wrong acces to mark and name in the second part of the condition. a.mark should be a->mark.

Comment: Note that `*a.mark` is the same as `*(a.mark)` and *not* `(*a).mark`. Better to use `a->mark`.

Comment: What is the type of `total_student` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you defined the function `compare` within another function or the reason of the error is another syntax error that precedes the line with the function definition.

You may not define a function within another function. Instead of the function you could define a lambda expression.

Place the function definition in a namespace.

Moreover the function definition is invalid due to incorrect member accesses. At least you should write

```
bool compare(const student *a, const student *b) 
{
    return a->mark < b->mark || (a->mark == b->mark && a->name < b->name); 
}
```

Also it looks confusing that you have a vector of pointers. If you have a vector of objects of the type `student` then the function definition will look like

```
bool compare(const student &a, const student &b) 
{
    return a.mark < b.mark || (a.mark == b.mark && a.name < b.name); 
}
```

Or you could write

```
#include <tuple>

//...

bool compare(const student &a, const student &b) 
{
    return std::tie( a.mark, a.name )  < std::tie( b.mark, b.name ); 
}
```